# Converting image from pdf not working in php

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have ghostscript and imagemagick installed in my C drive and i have my wamp server in D drive in which one file has code

```
<?php exec('convert "sd.pdf[0]" -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 "document.png"'); 
?>
```

The file sd.pdf exists in the folder in which my program is.This program is giving no error but also its not making a image in that folder.Why?
Additional Question:-Is using Imagemagick and ghostscript in php makes the program slower or faster?

Comment: is convert in the path of your shell? does your webserver userID have write permissions in that directory? is ghostscript executable/reachable by the webserver ID?

Comment: the problem was only with double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove or escape double quotes, it is not working correctly on Windows.
Take a look at my execute() method for more: https://github.com/webarto/instagraph/blob/master/instagraph.php#L55

```
public function execute($command)
{
    # remove newlines and convert single quotes to double to prevent errors
    $command = str_replace(array("\n", "'"), array('', '"'), $command);
    # replace multiple spaces with one
    $command = preg_replace('#(\s){2,}#is', ' ', $command);
    # escape shell metacharacters
    $command = escapeshellcmd($command);
    # execute convert program
    exec($command);
}
```

Chat with one of IM biggest contributors...

> Without any quotes, rgb(255,   255,   255)  WITH SPACES will cause
>   problems. Similarly the # in the hex values may cause problems if not
>   quoted. Double quotes are required if on windows or if using a
>   variable. Otherwise, single or double quotes are fine for IM. But if
>   you are calling the IM command from PHP exec, then as you know, you
>   need to be careful (or escape them).